# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError chilkat java library error in web application

Tags: java, web-applications, chilkat, chilkat-email

I am developing one java web application using eclipse IDE and deploying the application on google app engine.

I added chilkat.jar in WEB-INF->lib folder but still getting this **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.swig_module_init()V**.

I also tried from project properties-> java build path-> add external jar option, still getting this error. How to resolve this issue while using chilkat.jar in java web application.

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp

My guess is that the JVM class loader found and loaded the chilkat.jar, but it cannot find the native libchilkat.so.

The way to solve this problem is to ask:  In what directories is the Java runtime looking for native libs?   Clearly, the libchilkat.so is not in any of those directories.   There are generally three ways the directories are specified (as described at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp).   If you are running your Java code in an environment where other directories are searched, then examine more closely the documentation for that particular environment.

Alternatively, you can skip the entire convoluted mess of "what directories are searched" and instead just explicitly load the libchilkat.so by calling System.load and passing the full absolute path.  This is shown at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp

Comment: There is no libchilkat.so file in the downloaded folder. Also why can't i use just chilkat.jar by putting it in WEB-INF->lib folder.

Comment: I downloaded, extracted, and libchilkat.so is there.   If it wasn't present Chilkat would be hearing about it from many others..